# Negation is not detected in simple expression

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I have simple question. I have a simple expression used in a when-condition:

`<simple>${body} !contains '"foo' || ${body} !contains '"bar"' </simple>`

Due to unknown reason, I get a syntax error exception when starting the bundle on OSGi (unexpected token:!) But as I can read from the documentation, `!contains` is valid part of the simple expression language of Camel.

Does anybody now my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care! Since Camel 3 the documentation is splitted for 2.x and 3.x. Notice the small dropdown with default setting `latest` in the top right corner. You can change it to `2.x`

I guess you are running Camel 2.x and if you have a look at the [Camel Simple 2.x docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/languages/simple-language.html) for this version, it is `not contains`.

In contrast to the `!contains` of [Camel Simple 3.x](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html) you found in the latest docs.